# Express (or Koa) vs Micro

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create Node.js Microservices.
Each microservice will do one thing but should expose some extra endpoints to get information statistics about it (checking if alive, checking memory, etc').

What are the advantages of the npm package "Micro" over "Express" (or "Koa")?

Comment: I am also interested in what people think about this as we are beginning down the Node microservice architecture. Koa was created by the same author as Express to embrace new ECMA features, yet Express is still moving at full speed.